# why minipage environment prevents \thepage counter update?

Tags: page-numbering, minipage

Here is the code, that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[7]
\end{minipage}
current page = \thepage

\end{document}
```

All text in minipage appears on the second page (this is the desired behavior), but I get 'current page = 1' on the second page. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous page breaking of TeX. `\thepage` in the document body is not reliable. Use it only in headers and footers. In the document body use `\label{A}\pageref{A}`.

Comment: I've been wondering ... do you mark code according to a specific pattern? Do you mind if your posts are edited to format all code as code?

Comment: Well I'm *trying* to mark all commands but sometimes I overlook one (like I overlook typing errors). I don't mind if someone correct them but I also don't think it is really necessary when there is no danger of misunderstanding.